# How to use dojo.xhrPost properly?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, dojo

Here is my JS:

```
<script>
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");

function sendText(){
  var button = dijit.byId("submitButton2");

  dojo.connect(button, "onClick", function(event){
    // The parameters to pass to xhrPost, the message, and the url to send it to
    // Also, how to handle the return and callbacks.
    var xhrArgs = {
    //type: "POST",
      url: "http://testjson.php",
      content: dojo.toJson({key1:"value1",key2:"value2"},true),
      handleAs: "text",
      load: function(newContent){
        dojo.byId("response2").innerHTML = newContent;
      },
      error: function(error){
        // We'll 404 in the demo, but that's okay.  We don't have a 'postIt' service on the
        // docs server.
        dojo.byId("response2").innerHTML = "Message posted.";
      }
    }
    dojo.byId("response2").innerHTML = "Message being sent..."
    // Call the asynchronous xhrPost
    var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
  });
}
dojo.ready(sendText);
    </script>
```

Here is my PHP:

```
    <?php 

foreach($_POST as $key => $val) echo '$_POST["'.$key.'"]='.$val.'<br />';

?>
```

The problem is that nothing is being returned.
If I put `content` instead of `postData` I have $_POST[0]='{', $_POST[1]='k' etc character by character, limited to 1000. This is a big problem.

Please can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? I got this code right from the dojo website, so it should be alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php `$_POST` array only shows form encoded data. In your example you are POSTing json, so it won't directly show up in `$_POST`.

You have a couple options here. You could continue to post the data as json and read the POSTed json directly from the php input stream: `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`. This is probably the easiest, and it replaces accessing the `$_POST` array for the data.

Other options include not POSTing json (just send form encoded data) and POSTing json *as* form encoded data:

In that case, your `content` would become something like

`content: 'my_post_data='+dojo.toJson({key1:"value1",key2:"value2"}, true),` (you may need to change `handleAs` fyi)

Then on the server side you would likely see something like

`$_POST['my_post_data']= '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'` which could be processed by `json_decode()`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `content` is being sent character by character because you are converting your content object into JSON. According to [the dojo.xhrPost documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/xhrPost.html), the `content` property is expected to be a JavaScript Object. I hope this helps solve your problem.

It should be noted that this module is deprecated in favor of [dojo/request/xhr](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/xhr.html#dojo-request-xhr), so it is better to use that unless you have lower version requirements.

Comment: thx both I've somehow succeed in transmitting data, item by item in order to avoid size problems.